# How to audit folder permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, audit

Is there an easy way to list out the permissions granted to a folder (and sub folders) on a Windows 2003 server? I want to know which users/groups have what permissions for c:\myfolder and all the folders within it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to know who has access, and not the actual permissions I suggest you take a look at the sysinternals tool [AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[DumpSec](http://www.systemtools.com/somarsoft/?somarsoft.com) is also a useful tool for listing DACLS