# Getting ACL's from a Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-permissions

I would like to have a tool that shows ACL's for all folders on a share on a server(Win2k3). I have tried using srvcheck but would like something that goes into sub folders and shows security settings as well if possible.

Maybe I am simply not using it correctly?

Comment: Would [`cacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) work, or are you looking for only ACLs of folders?

Comment: Are you just looking to [audit {accessenum}](http://serverfault.com/questions/96986/how-to-audit-folder-permissions) access, or did you need to export the full ACL?

Comment: And what do you mean by *"show"*? *"Show"* as in *"list precisely"* or as in *"give me a colored pie-chart with hardly any relation to the real state of affairs"*?

Answer (score 3):

How about SysInternals' AccessEnum?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332

Answer (score -1):

Look what I just found for you:

http://brothertu.blogspot.com/2010/07/command-line-to-check-remote-share.html

RMTSHAR.exe.  A Microsoft tool.  The download is from Microsoft's FTP.

Usage: RMTSHARE \\server \\server\sharename

Share permissions are inherited all the way down, unless you have a share inside a share.

Also I don't know what you mean by "show security settings as well."